# Can we use finally to close connection of database other than a destructor in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, exception, singleton, finally

```
<?php
namespace database {
    class mysql_db
    {
        private static $instance;

        public static $connection;

        public function __construct($host=null, $user=null, $password=null,$db=null)
        {
            if(!self::$instance && !$host) {
                throw new \Exception("Missing Database..!!!");
            }

            $link = mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");

            if(!$link) {
                echo "<div style='text-align:center'><h1>Not able to connect</h1></div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div style='text-align:center'><h1>Connected</h1></div> <br />";
            }            

        public static function getInstance()
        {
            try {
                if(!self::$instance) {
                    self::$instance=new static('localhost','root','','xam');
                }
            } catch(\Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught Error: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }
    }

    $h= mysql_db::getInstance();
}
?>
```

So firstly as you can see that here I had used constructor to open the database connection and after the constructor is being called the connection itself gets closed but the question is whether we can use the finally block after the `try`/ `catch` as, according to me, after the `try` and `catch` the finally block will itself be called and always called whether the code executes or not and how I can use this block to close the connection?

Comment: This script seems like it's going in circles a bit...what are you trying to store in `self::$instance`? The mysql database connection? If so, this seems very muddy.

Comment: In the property $instance by default it has NULL and  I am trying to store the data i.e. **host_name, user_name, password and db_name** and since that property holds it and with the help of **self::$instance** I can use that data anywhere in class.

Comment: So does that part work then? You just want to know now the best way to close the connection, if it exists?

Comment: Yeah it woks well. Thanks!

Comment: How does it do it if you don't assign `$link` to anything? Presumably you have more script you aren't showing (perhaps why your `__construct()` is missing a close `}`?

Comment: I had done correction...Ty

Comment: What correction?